# scrapy export to database multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from website to database, The table is supposed to contain repetitive data for which I would require one row to be split into multiple tables to maintain normal forms.

The data is something like this,

```
[department, professor, student, marks, subject]
```

naturally, department and professor will repeat for many [student, marks, subject]. TO make the data normalized, I need to make it,

```
[sr. no., department, professor] and [dept.sr.no (reference), student, marks, subject]
```

How can I achieve this with scrapy? Would super classing department table help?

Answer (score 0):

Make items for each table，then in the pipeline use isinstance determine the Item object.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, DepartmentItem):
            return self.store_department(item, spider)
        elif isinstance(item, ProfessorItem):
            return self.store_professor(item, spider)
```